# Dealing with Frames - Python Webdriver

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have the following code which is looking for two Frames and then clicks the a link.

This code works in Chrome and Firefox. In IE though the tests just sit on this page and never do anything at all. In Safari, I get an error that the frame doesn't exist which is hogwash, as I can see it in the Safari developer tools. So I am wondering how to make this work across all browsers.

```
try:
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('iFrm')
    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
    print "Navigated to iFrm frame"
except:
    raise InvalidSwitchToTargetException(msg="Couldn't find the iFrm frame")
try:
    nav_frame = driver.find_element_by_id('nav')
    driver.switch_to_frame(nav_frame)
    print "Navigated to nav frame"
except:
    raise InvalidSwitchToTargetException(msg="Couldn't find the nav frame")
```

Comment: Could you try to switch to the frames by index instead, e.g. `switch_to_frame(0)`?

Comment: @alecxe using index yields the same results. IE nothing happens and it sits there like a bumpkin. Safari says it can't find the frames

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Do you know on which step is it hanging? Any errors on the console?

Comment: IE shows no errors. Safari fails in the first try block and says it can't find the frame. I honestly believe that IE would just sit there forever if I didn't manually stop the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [*Explicit Wait*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) *for the frame to become present* can help in case of Safari:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'iFrm')))

driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
```

Comment: thank you very much. This works very very well for Safari. Any thoughts on everyone's favourite browser, IE?

Comment: @DarthOpto sure, just one thought for now about this perfect program to download real browsers: try to upgrade `ie` and `selenium` to the latest versions..

Comment: We are using IE11, and the latest version of Selenium, still nothing.

Comment: for IE would you recommend a javascript? I have tried finding it by XPATH, NAME, ID, and CSSSelector and none of them are working. The test just sits there and does nothing with the frame. If you do recommend a javascript, any recommendations for that?

Comment: I found the problem with IE. It was a call further up in the script which wasn't working quite rightly. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DarthOpto thank you for sharing and sorry for not coming back to you - got out of ideas - ie is killing me.